# How to export with TableTools, all pages of a DataTable using server-side?

Tags: datatables, server-side, tabletools

I was looking for how to export all pages in a table built with server-side, but all the answers didn't works here. If I choose to print came all data in the table, but the others options came only the current page.

Is it possible load the first page, draw the table and in background built the others pages?

Thanks,

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get all data from Buttons extension (Excel)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32954834/get-all-data-from-buttons-extension-excel)