# Get all data from Buttons extension (Excel)

Tags: c#, datatables

We've got a DataTable working with paging - no problem.  There's a requirement to include an "Export to Excel" button.  So, we added the "Buttons" extension and have the data exporting just fine.  The problem is this:  it's only exporting the current page's data, not the entire set of data.  How can I get the entire set of data?  Is it possible?

```
$("dataTable-custom").dataTable({
    "paging": 1,
    buttons: ['excel],
    "serverSide": true,
    "ajax": {
        "url": "local\get",
        "data": ...
        }
```

Comment: Not the cause of problem, but `"paging": 1` is completely unnessecary (true by default) and _should_ either way be a boolean. There are some boolean evaluations in the code I'm afraid could cause unexpected behavior if you assign numbers to `paging`.

Comment: @davidkonrad...useful comment

Comment: I've explained it on how I've done it this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32692618/how-to-export-all-rows-from-datatables-using-ajax/38747601#38747601

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Neither [Buttons](https://datatables.net/extensions/buttons/) extension nor  [TableTools](http://datatables.net/extensions/tabletools/) extension (now retired and replaced by [Buttons](https://datatables.net/extensions/buttons/)) have the ability to export all data in server-side processing mode. See [this comment](https://www.datatables.net/forums/discussion/comment/45470/#Comment_45470) from the author of jQuery DataTables.

You can either:

- switch to client-side processing which may not be the option with large datasets, or
- implement Excel generation on the server by sending it the same request that was used to generate the table. Use [`ajax.params()`](http://datatables.net/reference/api/ajax.params%28%29)  to get the data submitted by DataTables to the server in the last Ajax request.