# JQuery Datatable defered loading export data to pdf, excel etc. not showing all records

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, datatables

I'm loading data in the datatables througn ajax using

```
$('#DTable').DataTable( {
    "processing": true,
    "serverSide": true,
    "ajax": {
        "url": "/api/admin/business-ad"
    },
    "dom": 'Bfrtip',
    "buttons": [
       'copy', 'csv', 'excel', 'pdf', 'print'
    ]
});
```

considering I have 100 records in the database,
at first this loads 10 records from the database. But while exporting the data to pdf/other, only that 10 records are exported. 
Is there any way to export all the records instead of getting only the displayed record.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get all data from Buttons extension (Excel)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32954834/get-all-data-from-buttons-extension-excel)

Comment: I've explained it how I've done it this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32692618/how-to-export-all-rows-from-datatables-using-ajax/38747601#38747601

Answer (score 0):

Try to include this in `datatable({})` function.

```
ordering: false,
```

also insert `exportOptions: {rows: {order: 'current',search: 'none'},},` inside `buttons:[{}]`

**e.g:**

```
$('#Example').DataTable({
ordering: false,
buttons: [{
text: 'PDF', 
exportOptions: 
{rows: {order: 'current',search: 'none'},},
```